# Analysis of the differences between beetle communities in four different forest types

Tags: r, pca, biostatistics

I'm working on my thesis but I have a problem making the last analysis.

I have 4 different kind of forest: a, b, c and d. Each kind of forest has been analyzed in 15 different places (so we have a1, a2 ... a15, b1, b2,...).

Now in each of these plots I have collected all the beetles and identified them. I obtain a community matrix with 28 beetle species and 60 plots going from a1 to d15.

I want to analyze the differences among those communities, and identify if the beetle populations in a, b, c and d are the same or not.

I wanted to use a PCA (Principal Component Analysis) but I can't seem to find a good explanation on how to do it with this kind of data.

Comment: Rows are your samples and columns are species. PCA will only visualize the data in less dimensions. I suggest reading [Tree diversity analysis](http://www.worldagroforestry.org/downloads/publications/PDFs/B13695.pdf) by Kindt and Coe. They explain multivariate methods and provide R code on how to do it. The corresponding package relies heavily on `vegan`.

Comment: Are you interested in your "number of plot in each forest" variable (that goes from 1 to 15)? From your description it sounds as if you do not. Then you could add up (or average) all your beetles in each forest type across plots, simplifying your data down to $4 \times 28$ matrix.